# Windows Phone webview flickering when keyboard is shown

Tags: windows-phone-8, webview, windows-phone

I'm now developing a webapp for Windows Phone 8 with Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone. I have a fullscreen webview that load html content from the web.

In the css of the html content there is this code:

```
@-ms-viewport{
   width:850px;
   user-zoom:fixed;
   max-zoom:1;
   min-zoom:1;
}
```

When the keyboard show up, there is an horrible flickering effect of a strange black rectangle.

I have only the webview component in the code and I use VB. There is any type of solution to fix this flickering effect?

Thank you

Comment: Is it flickering on emulator or in device or both?